# How to specify to sublime text whether I want to run my python code with python2.7 or python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the script package to run my python code in sublime text but it has no way to specify whether to run it with python3 or 2, and since all of my libraries are in python3 I need it to run with it too, is there a way to do this or do I just have to uninstall python2.7 all together to coerce it to run with python3. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a plug-in called Anaconda for sublime using package control. It'll turn your text editor into IDE. With Anaconda you can manually set which python interpreter to use using project settings. You can even set it to custom Python Virtualenv.

For ref:

[Setting up Sublime Text 3 for Full Stack Python Development](https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/)

[Configure Anaconda the Right Way](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you dont need create a new build system or specify the absolute path. Edit already existing python build system.

In `SublimeText\Data\Packages\` create folder `Python` -> like this `SublimeText\Data\Packages\Python\`
In this folder, create a file `Python.sublime-build` , it will overwrite the existing python build system.

In this file write [(python launcher documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "py -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
}
```

For choosing version of python interpretator, in the first line of your scripts write[(shebang lines)](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)

`#! python` or
`#! python3`

Comment: I am using linux

Comment: Normally linux/unix binaries (programs) do not have an extension (unlike windows that uses .exe). The default location for python should be in '/usr/bin/python', so in that case you would have: `{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}` I'm not sure where other versions of python would be installed in linix so you will have to search for that using `locate python`